# Couldn't find a matching Java operation for WSDD operation

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, axis

I hv created a web service for the following code but am getting an exception:

> org.apache.axis.InternalException: java.lang.Exception: Couldn't find a matching Java operation for WSDD operation "andrQues" (0 args)" on invoking the function.

```
public class Ques {
    public String[] AndrQues(){
        String ques[] = {"name??", "age??", "grade??"};
        return ques;
    }

}
```

Does anyone know why its occuring? Also the wsdl is not getting generated.

Comment: should it be "AndrQues" or "andrQues"?

Comment: yeah you are right. It should be andrQues.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the error.
Just need to change the "AndrQues" to "andrQues" and program runs fine.

Comment: I can't believe this was the problem! I spent several frustrating hours digging for a solution. Thanks for sharing!!!

Answer (score 4):

There is something wrong with your method name make sure that you have spelled your method Name correct. take care about the thing that use your method first latter in small means lower case.

just u need to change **"AndrQues"** to **"andrQues"** because by Default the web-services taking name into the lower case.

this will help..

Answer (score 0):

In my case, entry into the interface **WSPort.java** invoking **WSSoapHttpBindingImpl.java** was missing.

```
public interface <classname> extends java.rmi.Remote 
{
   public <methodname>(<params>) throws java.rmi.RemoteException;
}
```